# Does Groupon provide an official way to connect to their user accounts?

Tags: groupon

Is there an official way provided by Groupon to connect remotely to a user's account using password/username?
I am asking because on dealsgoround.com you can automatically connect your Groupon account and save all your vouchers to their database. 
I couldn't figure out how they are doing it.

Answer (score 1):

[Groupon API](http://www.groupon.com/pages/api) - this was the first Google hit - did you try searching first?

Comment: on 20Jul2015 logging in and clicking the My API Key link goes to a 404 :/